# Xamarin.Designer.DesignerException in Axml Designer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception message:

> Bridge [resources.resolve] Couldn't resolve resource
>   @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DarkBridge [resources.resolve] Couldn't
>   resolve resource
>   @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Darkjava.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   Attribute '?attr/colorPrimaryDark' not found. Are you using the right
>   theme?
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:76)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:270)
>         at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:742)
>         at android.view.View.(View.java:3948)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:573)
>         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:203)
>         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:199)
>         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:195)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>         at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>         at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:170)
>         at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:640)
>         at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:87)
>         at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Bridge [resources.format] Failed to convert ?attr/colorPrimaryDark into a drawableBridge [resources.resolve] Couldn't resolve resource
>   @style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1Bridge [resources.resolve]
>   Couldn't resolve resource
>   @style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1java.lang.NullPointerException
>       mono.android.DesignerException
>         at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:186)
>         at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:640)
>         at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:87)
>         at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I can't use the Designer, I downloaded all the support libraries asked of me, and all other layouts show up just right except this one.

Answer (score 0):

`TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1` is a style and not a TextAppearance attribute:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But the app runs just fine, and would a simple error break the whole visual designer?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there maybe a warning in the logcat when you run it?